# I need to use regular expression for drop down list item, But using regular i am facing an issue

Tags: jmeter

In application

For lender. 
1. Lender will have list orders
2. So i selected lender from the drop down 
3. Then list of order has to be displayed in the screen.
4. Then clicking on Broadcast order
5. Then clicking on Submit button
6. Logout from application
This is my script

After using regular expression on the step 2
Then in step 3 the script is failing
Y because , the Autoselected lender using jmeter. Does not have any orders. So jmeter is searching for the orders. Jmeter dint found any order so the script is failed .
So here what i have to do
PFA

[Clicking on Broadcast on ur selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKT0x.jpg)

but this is happening

[No oders to click broadcast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWIwL.jpg)

Pls help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value of Lender in the request that you sent in 2nd step.

```
2. So i selected lender from the drop down
```

You can find the parameter where you are sending Lender value in the request body. change the value from "siva test" (who does not have any orders) to a name "New Lender" (who has some orders, as per the screen shot) who has order list and try to replay. Add Debug Sampler and View Results Tree Listener to validate the requests.

**Share the screen shot of http sampler for the second step, where you send the request for Lender's order list.**

Once you get the second step working, you can parameterize this value using CSV DataSet Config, so that multiple Lenders can be picked up by different threads/vusers in different iterations